# Как отключить кэширование JS в модуле к CS Cart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cms, cs-cart

Возникла потребность в отключении кэширования JavaScript в конкретном модуле (написанном не мной). Написана простая функция, которая убирает братьев у элементов с конкретным текстом внутри. Данный модуль зависим от БД и поэтому обновляется динамически, а значит кэширование JS ненужно и даже не желательно.

Понятно, что есть несколько путей решения данной задачи:

1. Найти запрос к базе и его изменить, но с этим возникли сложности, так как в CS cart я пришел недавно.
2. Как раз заключается в том методе, что я описал выше. По факту, нужно отключить кэширование одного модуля, а не всей CMS.

Жду конструктивных советов. Спасибо